# iOS App with web contents got rejected even the similar one is in appstore

Tags: objective-c, ios7, app-store, appstore-approval, iphone-5

I have developed a native iOS application based on client's requirement to show the timelines of different social networks (FB, Twitter, Instagram, Google + etc.) in the same application using a webview.

Say for example, when I click Facebook button it will show the web contents of Facebook  and so. The client gave me a reference app which is doing the same thing and published in the appstore.

That is https://itunes.apple.com/sa/app/mysocial-for-ios/id687623816?mt=8

(Is it not a native app ?)

But when I tried to publish the similar app into appstore,it got rejected. I got the same reason mentioned in the link http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-215050.html?s=b15f82172b608c468a36774a93c7a7c9

Could you just tell me what is wrong and why the other app got published and what to do for publishing it to the appstore.

Comment: what do you want us to say? you broke app store rules and the other one got lucky. Go native or at least use some native features. otherwise it makes no sense to make an app if you have a webpage.

Comment: Sorry I am not intended to blame anybody.I have asked out of curiosity whether they have done something more to convince apple to push it to appstore.Afterall,I am doing it not out my personal interest but out of somebody's requirement.

Comment: Also I have added native feature to post the user status to all the social networks.But the apple did not allow even.

Comment: It looks like your app doesn't add much that couldn't be done with a web app. Therefore, it is difficult that you get your app accepted through the current review system. You have two options: either create a new appID and submit it as a new app (there are chances that your app gets reviewed by a less strict reviewer) or add some functionality and explain it in the notes for the reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly according to the Apple rules any Application who uses Webview or Webkit with just loading links & with not any other features will get rejected immediately.

I did checked reference application you shared it presented & controlled in a way that doesn't looks like an web view based Application. May be they have developed it on any cross platform.

And there is possibility if they are using the web components to load the links but they are using it smartly & they are making it controllable. So there are every chances you can make proper research & try to get the idea how you can utilise the web components smartly & try to make similar application.

**Important Note :**

- The most prior thing is it should be user friendly & easy navigation for users.

Hope this helps to everyone.